# Azure Application Gateway, ISTIO and TLS

Tags: azure, ssl, istio

I am dealing with the SSL connection from the Azure Web Appplication Firewall to the Kubernetes Cluster via ISTIO.

The connection from the client to the Azure WAF is already TLS encrypted.

As far as I understand, I have to encrypt the data again in the WAF. Can I use the same certificates that I already used for the connection to the WAF?

Here I would proceed as described in this article:
[application-gateway-end-to-end-ssl-powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-end-to-end-ssl-powershell)

Then I have to deposit the same certificates in Istios Ingress Gateway.
As mentioned here:
[Configure a TLS ingress gateway](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/secure-ingress/)

```
> cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
>  
> 
>    apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
>     kind: Gateway
>     metadata:
>       name: mygateway
>     spec:
>       selector:
>         istio: ingressgateway # use istio default ingress gateway
>       servers:
>       - port:
>           number: 443
>           name: https
>           protocol: HTTPS
>         tls:
>           mode: SIMPLE
>           serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
>           privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
>         hosts:
>         - "httpbin.example.com"
>     EOF
```

Is that correct so far?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the same certificate you specified in the application gateway (so the certificate application gateway expects) in the istio gateway. your gateway configuration looks valid, as long as the cert is the same and host is the same.

Comment: So I mean the client (e.g. webbrowser from the user) connects via the WAF. Here I have certificate 1, for the secure connection. The data transfer is analyzed here and encrypted again at the end. Can I now use the same certificate 1 in ISTIO or do I have to use an additional certificate?

Comment: we are using the same one

Comment: I'll try it and get back to you tomorrow and mark your answer as corect accordingly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can use application gateway backend health blade to check the error you are getting, if the cert is wrong it would say something like that

Comment: any luck yet, mate?

Comment: hey i have tried to set the certificates a few times, but i had no luck. A colleague is currently looking at the matter and is trying to find the source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

For me, finally it worked. 
I have a situation, Application Gateway deployed with its own VirtualNetwork and Subnet. 
So i made Vnet Peering and thought it would be enough. But it didn't.
After some days of struggling, i have found out my VirtualNetwork Subnet is the same as docker network inside AKS.
When i have recreated ApplicationGateway with new subnet, which does not cover any part of docker subnet, it worked.